# dc.js Scatter Plot with Vertical Brush

Tags: dc.js

We are preparing to upgrade our application from dc.js v2 & d3.js v3 to the latest code dc.js v3.0.6 and d3.js 5.6.  18 months ago as we were getting with dc.js we developed our own vertical brushing for the scatter plot.

I was interested when I notice dc.js v3 coordinateGridMixin had a new method brush([]).  I saw all the notes and cautions, but was hoping it would be simple to use just a vertical brush on the scatter plot by defining

```
.brush(d3.brushY())
```

So now the scatter plot only allows vertical brushing visually, but of course errors occur because scatter plot is expecting 2 dimensional brushing by default and it has override coordinateGridMixin brushing code.

What is the best ay to approach my requirement to only allow vertical brushing on a scatter plot?

Comment: I took a look at it today. You end up having to replace a lot of internal functions, so it's a lot of monkey patching. I think it would be easier to just hack on `src/scatter-plot.js` and maybe `src/filters.js` to include the support. Feel free to open an issue if you want to discuss how to do this. I don't think it's all that hard, just a few places need to be generalized. I could point you to the code to look at.